# Using PHP to add to MySQL adds twice and issue with foreign id constraint

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason, when I add to my database, this line
    `$query = "INSERT INTO customers (id, name, address) VALUES (NULL,'$name', '$address')";` adds the customer twice. So one customer would have both id 1 and id 2. The subsequent getting of `$last_id` will always get the second id number, so for customer entered with id 1 and 2, `$last_id == 2`. I'm eliminating the issue by deleting first copy, but how do I keep it from happening in the first place? I'm using Chrome, but it happens in safari as well.

```
<?php 
// Include the ShoppingCart class.  Since the session contains a
// ShoppingCard object, this must be done before session_start().
require "../application/cart.php";
session_start(); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php 

$orderErr = $nameErr = $addressErr = "";
$name = $address = "";

// If this session is just beginning, store an empty ShoppingCart in it.
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = new ShoppingCart();
}

if (($_SESSION['cart']->count_order()) == 0) {
    $orderErr = "There is nothing in the order, cannot checkout";

}

// sanitizing function
function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
    }
    else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["address"])) {
        $addressErr = "Address is required";
    } 
    else {
        $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
   }

    //if there is an order, and name and address exist after sanaitizing,
    // add to db
    if ($name != "" && $address != "" && ($_SESSION['cart']->count_order()) != 0) {
        require_once 'login.php';
        $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
        if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);

        //adding current customer
        $query = "INSERT INTO customers (id, name, address) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$address')";
        echo "ok<br>";

        $result = $conn->query($query);
        if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully" . "<br>";
            $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
            echo $last_id . "<br>";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
        $delete_id = $last_id - 1;

        // deleting duplicate
        $query = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE id = '$delete_id'";
        if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
            echo "duplicate deleted successfully" . "<br>";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

        //send orders to db
        $_SESSION['cart']->send_order_to_db($last_id, $conn);

        $conn->close();

        session_unset();  // remove all session variables
        session_destroy();


    }
}

?>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Checkout</title>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Checkout</h2>

<p>Here is your order: <?php
// Poor man's display of shopping cart
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = new ShoppingCart();
}
$_SESSION['cart']->table();
?></p>
<span class="error"><?php echo $orderErr;?></span>

<h3> Checkout Form: </h3>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method = "post" >
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
    Address: <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $address;?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

<p>Your credit card will be billed.  Thanks for the order!</p>

<p><a href="index4.php">Shop some more!</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

The second issue is, the function **SOLVE. SEE EDIT BELOW**

```
public function send_order_to_db($last_id, $conn) {
      foreach ($this->order  as $variety => $quantity)
        $query = "INSERT INTO orders (id, variety, quantity) VALUES" .
          "('$last_id', '$variety', '$quantity')";

        echo 'added ' . $quantity . ' ' . $variety;

        $result = $conn->query($query);
        if (!$result) echo "INSERT failed: $query<br>" .
          $conn->error . "<br><br>";
    }
```

which I call after entering the customer's information, only adds the last element from the array $this->order. Is it because foreach does not work like a loop? So then I'd use a for loop right? Or does this have something to do with the database?

**EDIT**
I realized I did not have brackets around the foreach statement. Now that I do, it works. Adds all orders and all have the same id.

Here's my database:

```
/* To start with a fresh new database named store, we will delete one
 * if one already exists:
 */
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS store;

CREATE DATABASE store;


GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON store.* to user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'name';

USE store;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers (
 id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name text NOT NULL,
 address text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB; 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (
 id int NOT NULL,
 variety varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 quantity int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id, variety),
 FOREIGN KEY (id)
 REFERENCES customers(id)
 ON DELETE CASCADE
 ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem 1

Your first problem being that the record is inserted twice is because you're running the query twice:

```
$result = $conn->query($query);
if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
```

You should use the `$result` contents to check whether it worked or not instead of re-running the query:

```
$result = $conn->query($query);
if ($result === true) {
```

## Problem 2

The record only inserts the last record - this is because you aren't using braces for your `foreach` loop, so it only runs the first line after the control structure in the loop - the rest will only execute once the loop has completed. See commented flow:

```
public function send_order_to_db($last_id, $conn) {
    foreach ($this->order  as $variety => $quantity)
        // This line is run in the loop
        $query = "INSERT INTO orders (id, variety, quantity) VALUES" .
                 "('$last_id', '$variety', '$quantity')";
        // This line is only run once, after the foreach has finished
        echo 'added ' . $quantity . ' ' . $variety;
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        if (!$result)
            echo "INSERT failed: $query<br>" .
                 $conn->error . "<br><br>";
}
```

You just need to wrap the contents in braces:

```
public function send_order_to_db($last_id, $conn) {
    foreach ($this->order  as $variety => $quantity) {
        // This line is run in the loop
        $query = "INSERT INTO orders (id, variety, quantity) VALUES" .
                 "('$last_id', '$variety', '$quantity')";
        // So is all below now
        echo 'added ' . $quantity . ' ' . $variety;
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        if (!$result) {
            echo "INSERT failed: $query<br>" .
                 $conn->error . "<br><br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the braces after the `if` at the end aren't required, but it's good practice to use braces at all times for readability (and to help you find mistakes like this).

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the problem 2 already (see edits) but I didn't realize  `if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) ` runs the query twice. Why doesn't `$result = $conn->query($query);` run it twice?

Comment: You assign the query result to that variable (which runs it), then you are running the query again in the `if` statement. You could also remove the `$result` line to fix your issue.

Comment: so, `$query = "INSERT INTO customers (id, name, address) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$address')";` doesn't actually run it? I need `$conn->query($query)` to run it?

Comment: Correct :) the first line you just posted is simply defining the SQL command. The `$conn->query($query)` part executes it (which you were running twice)

Comment: Got it, can I run it by simply writing `$conn->query($query);`, and not having it as part of an assignment or if statement? Thanks by the way.

Comment: Yes, but then you can't validate the results of the query - which is why you assign it to `$result` so you can check the results later on without having to re-run the query.